# Excel to XML : dates to numbers?

Tags: excel, xml, date, numbers

I have an Excel file that is exportable to XML.
I have a problem with date columns.
When I export the Excel file to XML file, dates are converted to numbers.

I know that the numbers are the number of days since 01/01/1900.

Is there a way to export them as dates (i.e as they are in the Excel file) with minimum
changes in the Excel file.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to convert them to text versions of the date.  This can be done many ways, ie the TEXT formula, or through vba.

Comment: got it. An example though VBA ?